# undefined returned when adding a new property to an object

Tags: javascript

can someone make me understand why i get undefined in my output in the last line?

```
var protoRabbit = {     
    speak: function(line){         
        print_line(this.type+' says, '+this.line);         
        print_line(this.type+' says, '+line);     
    },
    kill : function (){
        console.log('killerRabbit is not killing');
    }
};
var killerRabbit = Object.create(protoRabbit);
killerRabbit.type='killer';
killerRabbit.line='killer here';
killerRabbit.speak('killer rabbit here');
print_line(killerRabbit.kill());
```

op as on console:

```
killer says, killer here
killer says, killer rabbit here
killerRabbit is not killing
undefined
```

why is undefined there when i added a property(kill function to the initial object) ?

P.S.
`print_line` is a custom function i made which takes an argument and prints output to console...

Comment: The `kill` function doesn't return anything, and the default returned value for any function is `undefined`

Comment: changed `console.log('killerRabbit is not killing');` to `return 'killerRabbit is not killing';` and undefined is not appearing in console anymore....

Comment: let me know how to mark it as the accepted answer for the question from my end

Comment: I'd suggest you just delete it, now that you know the answer. It is most certainly a duplicate as this has been asked many times before, and is a common issue.

Comment: this question was wreaking havoc for a cpl of hours and you have solved my very big concern....i am able to override default properties which i couldnt.....was not debugging properly and when i see undefined was like "WTF!!!"...
just changing it to `return` made my day.....